# Gaming Questions of the Week #3

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, blog, question-of-the-week

In an effort to try and keep the Question of the Week going, please submit your suggestions for this week!

### Sample Questions:

- First week's question - [Minecraft's World Size](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/minecrafts-world-size)
- Second weeks question - [Pokemon Missingno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19638/10)
- [Tips for not getting lost underground?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19817/10)
- [What is the optimal position of a sentry gun?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/what-is-the-optimal-position-of-a-sentry-gun)

If you want to nominate either of the two sample questions for this week, post them as an answer. Feel free to nominate any other questions you feel are deserving also. Also remember that the previous two questions were about Minecraft and Pokemon, so hopefully there's a new next best thing!

Comment: While we already had Minecraft recently, I'm expecting Portal 2 to take over that crown soon, so I think the Lost Underground question would make an excellent blog post

Comment: Actually, I think @Ivo is right, this **would** make an excellent blog post.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid another Minecraft question, I'd go with

[Optimum Mazing Path (by Length)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/optimum-mazing-path-by-length)

Comment: Because I didn't have anyone to blog about this we've went with the other answer. But I'm still open for anyone wanting to blog about this.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two suggested by Ivo Flipse, I have to go with:

[Tips for not getting lost underground?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19817/3114) - [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)

I'd like to say I'd prefer [What is the optimal position of a sentry gun?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/what-is-the-optimal-position-of-a-sentry-gun) - [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2) (because we've already had a Minecraft question), but I don't think the activity (comments, answers) of that one is as good as that of the Minecraft question.

---

Given free run of the week's questions I would nominate:

[Optimum Mazing Path (by Length)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/optimum-mazing-path-by-length) - [tower-defense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tower-defense)

Comment: This answer [has been bloggified](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/qotw/get-lost)